# UITableViewCell disappears after pressing minus in editing mode

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom TableViewCell with some labels, a slider, and a play button. If there is no audio file, the cell is not expandable, and the slider and play button are not visible. However, when there is audio, the cell expands to show everything.

If I enter editing mode and press the minus, it works as expected.

Now for the problem. The cell slides over to show the delete button. If I expand and contract the cell, then press the minus, it flies off the screen. Here's a gif so you can see what I mean.

[image]

Here are some methods I implemented

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! HistoryTBCell
    cell.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight
    cell.clipsToBounds = true
    tableView.beginUpdates()

    if cell.isExpandable == true {
        if toggle == 1 {
            selectedRow = indexPath
            toggle = 0
        } else {
            selectedRow = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 2)
            toggle = 1
        }
    }

    tableView.endUpdates()
}



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if selectedRow == indexPath {
        return 120
    } else {
        return 60
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    if self.tableView.editing {
        return .Delete
    } else {
        return .None
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! HistoryTBCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .None
    cell.clipsToBounds = true
    let hists = history[indexPath.row]

    let date = hists.valueForKey("currentDate") as! String
    let speechTime = hists.valueForKey("speechTime") as! String
    let actualTime = hists.valueForKey("actualTime") as! String
    let rec = hists.valueForKey("recURL") as! String

    cell.configure(date: date, speech: "Speech Time: \(speechTime)", actual: "Actual Time: \(actualTime)")

    if rec != "" {
        cell.setUpAudio(url: rec)
    }

    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Delete", message: "Are you sure you want to delete?\nThe recording will also be deleted", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .Default, handler: { void in
            //let context = self.appDelegate?.managedObjectContext
            let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
            let hists = self.history[indexPath.row]
            let rec = hists.valueForKey("recURL") as! String
            self.getContext().deleteObject(self.history[indexPath.row])
            self.history.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            do {
                try self.getContext().save()
            } catch {
                print("Could not save")
            }
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            do {
                let appended = rec
                let documentsDirectory = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
                let pathurl = documentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent(appended)
                try fileManager.removeItemAtPath(pathurl.path!)
            } catch {
                print("Could not remove item")
            }

        }))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))

        presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    selectedRow = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 2)
}
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the resizing. I can post more code if needed. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried getting inside the accessoryButtonTapped... delegate method and resetting selectedRow before deleting the row?  I wonder if it's because the reloading of the tableview shifts which cell becomes the new selectedRow?

Comment: please add code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` as well.

Comment: @creeperspeak Nothing I do in that delegate method seems to change anything.

Comment: @AdeelMiraj Done.

Comment: What do you have in that delegate method? Where is the code you are using to actually delete the rows?

Comment: I delete the rows in commitEditingStyle. I added the code

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was comment out this line:

```
cell.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight
```